# I need to delay the display of a Primefaces AJAX Status dialog by X milliseconds

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I need to delay the display of a Primefaces AJAX Status dialog by X milliseconds but OmniFaces ExceptionHandler reacts badly to javascript timeout solution.

Here's what I got so far:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="showStatusDialog();" onsuccess="hideStatusDialog();" onerror="hideStatusDialog();"/>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var statusDlgTimer = null;

    function showStatusDialog()
    {
        if (statusDlgTimer === null) 
        {
            statusDlgTimer = setTimeout("statusDialog.show()", 700);
        }
    }

    function hideStatusDialog()
    {
        if (statusDlgTimer !== null) 
        {
            clearTimeout(statusDlgTimer);
            statusDialog.hide();
            statusDlgTimer = null;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works perfectly as long as no error occurs in the AJAX call. I'm using OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler to handle AJAX/non-AJAX exceptions.

My hypothesis is that since the JavaScript is reloaded when the error page is rendered the reference to the statusDlgTimer is never detected to be !== null, but I've not yet been able to find a good workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` replaces basically the entire HTML document tree with the content of the error page and hereby the `<p:ajaxStatus>` "get lost" and its `oncomplete` is never invoked. You basically need to invoke `hideStatusDialog()` from inside the HTML source of the error page as well. Perhaps something like this:

```
<h:outputScript target="body">hideStatusDialog();</h:outputScript>
```

Better yet, use [`$(document).ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [`ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) and [`ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) in a global JS file instead of the whole `<p:ajaxStatus>`.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a collegue I actually found two other work arounds, the latter of which resembles BalusC's solution.

1. By setting a variable 'var displaydialog = false' onload and setting it to true before setting the timeout the dialog. I checked that same variable in an intermediary function before actually displaying the variable. A bit difficult and hackish but it worked.
2. My JavaScript was included in my Facelets template, which the error page also used. By creating another template I was able to use ui:insert to avoid inserting the JavaScript at all into the error page and the dialog is not displayed. I went with this solution.